# Standard CoffeeScript output layout

Tags: coffeescript, project

Is there any de facto standard for the filesystem output layout of compiled CoffeeScript output?

Or: where should the `.js` and `.map` files end up?

I currently have a file watcher<sup>1</sup> compiling the output to `./grounds/[whatever]` to keep the source folder clean, so I end up with something like:

```
index.html
/js
├──foo.js
├──bar.js
/coffee
├──a.coffee
├──b.coffee
├──/grounds
│  ├──a.js
│  ├──a.map
│  ├──b.js
│  ├──b.map
├──/some-module
│  ├──c.coffee
│  ├──/grounds
│  │  ├──c.js
│  │  ├──c.map
```

Just curious if I missed the boat on some existing standard for the output file layout, or if folks generally just let them all be siblings in the same folder and are happy with that.

<sub>1: Pycharm</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they is any standard, but for development, I use the same structure for the JS than for the coffee:

eg:

```
coffee
├── AdvancedStatsModule.coffee
├── board
│   ├── Board.coffee
│   ├── Card.coffee
├── controllers
│   ├── directives.coffee
│   ├── factory.coffee
│   ├── filters.coffee
│   ├── ListController.coffee

public/js
├── AdvancedStatsModule.js
├── board
│   ├── Board.js
│   ├── Card.js
├── controllers
│   ├── directives.js
│   ├── factory.js
│   ├── filters.js
│   ├── ListController.js
```

Advantages for this:

- JS and coffee are not mixed
- The coffee directory is not public

For production, I usually concat and minify my files anyway.

### Update:

I use gulp for that. My Gulpfile:

```
var watch= require('gulp-watch');
var coffee= require('gulp-coffee');

gulp.src(paths.coffee)
    .pipe(watch(function(files) {
        return files.pipe(coffee())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js));
         }));
```

Comment: Could you provide your compiler format string that results in this layout?